# Constant in same function throws up unresolved identifer

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I have the following piece of code which gives me the error

"Use of unresolved identifier 'randomcell'

But randomcell is clearly defined earlier on in the same function, why can the Else part not see it? I have tried redefining it inside the else part but it simply chooses another cell, I want to refer to the same random element in the second part of the function.

```
if seconds == 5 {
           let randomcell = viewArray.randomElement()
           randomcell?.backgroundColor = UIColor .red
           }
           else  {

               randomcell?.backgroundColor = UIColor .systemYellow
           }
```

Comment: randomcell is defined inside your if-closure. it isn't defined inside else-closure.
let randomcell = viewArray.randomElement() needs to be defined before your if statement

Comment: Okay. Thank you for answering. So how would I go about keeping track of the random element selected by the first part in order to change it in the second part?

Comment: You are using randomCell out if it's scope. If your else statement is executing, there is no definition of the randomcell. Define it before the if statment.

Comment: @πter Okay, thank you for your answer, that has resolved the error but not the issue, I want the else part to refer to the same randomly selected element, but it moves straight on to the next one, how do I keep track of the randomcell once it's defined, may I ask?

Comment: @Chris Thank you for advice, as stated to the other gentleman this has resolved the error but not the greater problem which is keeping track of a random element once it has been chose. Any ideas would be appreciated? kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let randomcell = viewArray.randomElement()
if seconds == 5 {
    randomcell?.backgroundColor = UIColor .red
}
else {
    randomcell?.backgroundColor = UIColor .systemYellow
}
// You can use your random cell
```

I would recommend you to go over the [Swift language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html). It's a really good introduction to the Swift language.

Comment: Thanks for your time I'll take a look. And if you do have any thoughts on how to reuse a randomly selected element that would be great. I've been to Košice by the way, it was a beautiful city at a beautiful time in my life, we sat in a large Germanic themed pub and had huge steins of beer. Take care.